# "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" when publishing Self-contained .Net Core 3.1 in VS2019

Tags: .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, tls1.2

I'm getting this error while trying to publish my .net core console app. There have been no apparent changes to the environment since last week which makes it very strange.

- Windows 10
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.3
- Package Manager Console Host Version 5.9.1.0
- NuGet Package Manager version 5.9.0

Here is the publish profile:

[image: Publish Profile Settings]

And the errors:

[image]

I've tried this, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out you need to specifically disable the TLS 1.1 in the registry.
If you don't have the 'TLS 1.1' key you need to create it first, then add the DWORD values just like for 'TLS 1.2'.

[image]